# Is it necessary to sync while opening a vs project directly from github

Tags: visual-studio, github, .net-core

I have a github repo with angular and dotnet core microservice files. I went to github and instead of downloading zip chose the option Open in Visual Studio. After cloning, it created some extra files with .csproj extension under each individual project. What should i do, keep them or undo changes. If I undo, will it cause any conflict next time I access and try to push any change?

Comment: Generally, these files are automatically excluded with the .gitignore file, you should be fine.

Comment: Those are listed under changes, won't I have to stage and commit at the end inorder to sync my local and remote repo? I am using a master branch for all.

Comment: Then just edit your .gitignore file to prevent these files from being tracked by git. You'll just have to commit changes for the .gitignore file then.

Comment: Have a look at some pre configured .gitignore based on your project and modify it as you need. https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Should I edit in github or local repo?

Comment: Both methods should do the trick. But if you edit on GitHub, make sure to pull the repo after to get your updated .gitignore file.